# Getting HTTP audio and then playing it back in android

Tags: java, android, http, audio

I have a API that takes a string and converts in into audio when I do a HTTP get in android. I want to be able to play it back when I recieve it but I don't know how to do this. Can someone help me. Here is my code so far:

```
public static String getHTML(String urlToRead) throws Exception {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    URL url = new URL(urlToRead);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
```